Extract (Wav) Sound from translate.google.com using Java 17
This question is based on Extract Sound from translate.google.com
I would like to get the audio of pronuntiation from google.
Here my code in Java 17.
package org.example;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TranslateTextFromPHP {


    private static final String GOOGLE_TRANSLATE_URL = "https://translate.google.com/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute";
    private static final String SOURCE_LANGUAGE = "en";
    private static final String TARGET_LANGUAGE = "es";
    private static final String TEXT_TO_translate = "hello";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String translatedText = translateWithGoogle(TEXT_TO_translate, SOURCE_LANGUAGE, TARGET_LANGUAGE);

        if (translatedText != null) {
            String audioData = extractAudioData(translatedText);
            if (audioData != null) {
                saveAudioFile(audioData, "test.mp3");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Could not extract audio data.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Translation failed.");
        }
    }

    private static String translateWithGoogle(String text, String sourceLanguage, String targetLanguage) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Integer number = 1;
        Object[] innerObbjects = new Object[]{text, sourceLanguage, targetLanguage, number};
        Object[] innerObbjects2 = new Object[]{innerObbjects, new Object[]{}};
        String jsonInner = mapper.writeValueAsString(innerObbjects2);
        Object[] middleObjects = new Object[]{
                "MkEWBc"
                , jsonInner, null,
                "generic"
        };
        Object[] outerObjects = new Object[]{new Object[]{middleObjects}};

        Map<String, Object> textData = new HashMap<>();
        textData.put("f.req", outerObjects);

        String bodyRequest = mapper.writeValueAsString(textData);
        System.out.println("bodyRequest: " + bodyRequest);

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(GOOGLE_TRANSLATE_URL))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(bodyRequest, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("response: " + response);
        System.out.println("response.body(): " + response.body());
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("bodyResponse: " + gson.toJson(response.body()));


        if (response.statusCode() == 200) {
            return response.body();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: HTTP Status Code - " + response.statusCode());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static String extractAudioData(String response) {
        String regex = "//NE[^\\\\]+#";
        if (response.matches(regex)) {
            String encodedAudio = response.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
            return new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedAudio));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void saveAudioFile(String audioData, String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
            outputStream.write(audioData.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        }
    }
}

My code is modified according to this image (to get the same JSON shown in Chrome {"f.req":[[["MkEWBc","[[\"hello\",\"en\",\"es\",1],[]]",null,"generic"]]]}):

But I got:

Obviously I can't revie my next steps due to error doing my request.
What is my mistake (because I'm receiving 400 error) in my code?
How to find in google-chrome (Developer-Tools) the response (with the pronuntiation of summitted text)?
EDIT 1:
I printed the response Body:
response: (POST https://translate.google.com/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute?rpcids=MkEWBc) 400
response.body(): )]}'

[["er",null,null,null,null,400,null,null,null,3],["di",15],["af.httprm",15,"-4285807505274075089",16]]
---
bodyResponse: ")]}\u0027\n\n[[\"er\",null,null,null,null,400,null,null,null,3],[\"di\",15],[\"af.httprm\",15,\"-4285807505274075089\",16]]"
Error: HTTP Status Code - 400
Error: Translation failed.

QUESTION 2:
Take in account that I'm traslating code from Python/PHP responses of original question, what are my mistakes translating them?

I don’t understand the sentence “My code is modified according to this image:” How does a screenshot of your web browser modify your program code?

using {System.out.println{ I can get the same JSON BodyRequest shown in Chrome: {"f.req":[[["MkEWBc","[[\"hello\",\"en\",\"es\",1],[]]",null,"generic"]]]}

So when you want to say that the request bodies are the same, why don’t you say exactly that, rather than what you said? So the request bodies are the same, but the URLs are clearly different and the headers might be different too (e.g. regarding cookies or authentication)… Besides that, you should not ignore the response body, just because the status code says “failed”. More than often, the response body contains a detailed error message.

I add the body response to find out what happens (it is not clear for me). About the headers as the question based and their responses (PHP and Python) I didn't see the use of headers, authentication, etc. I took the code from responses. Why would they be necessary in Java?
I suspect it is from my translation to Java

This response looks mangled. Maybe, you should just print the body exactly as received, instead of running it through gson.toJson(…).

I added multiple additional print! And I added another question related to Python/PHP responses.

Even at the Python code of the linked Q&A are comments saying that it doesn’t work (anymore). So why do you suspect that your translation to Java is the problem? Did you ever try the Python version? As already said, the page in the browser clearly uses a different URL, with a lot of encoded parameters but even the request body is not the same, as there is an at attribute in addition to the f.req attribute. Besides that, there’s still no sense in applying gson.toJson(…) to the result string and if you ever manage to get audio data, turning them into a String before saving will mangle it
